# Pitch Accent of verbs that end in なくなる and it's conjugations?

Tags: pitch-accent

If I had to guess I would see they all drop at NA but I'm not sure

食べなくな\る　食べなくな\った

遣らなくな\る　遣らなくな\った

I would say 食べなくなりま\した for the masu form

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: FYI https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99#%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3(?)